# Genders for arbitrary occupations

Tags: grammatical-number, sentence, pronouns, gender-neutral, feminine

Let's say I have a sentence similar to

> When a scientist publishes results, she must be careful to not enter the incorrect data.

However, I am confused as to what I should use in place of the "she".

Using a "she" to refer to an arbitrary scientist, to me, seems just as weird as referring to an arbitrary scientist as "he", while "they" just seems grammatically incorrect.

I have been told that the grammatically correct, gender neutral form of the sentence would be

> When a scientist publishes results, **he/she** must be careful to not enter the incorrect data.

But, come on, I'm not going to write "he/she" every time I have to refer to someone of unspecified gender.

---

How do I go about dealing with this? I understand that I could simply rephrase the sentence as

> When scientists publish results, they must be careful to not enter incorrect data.

This is what I do in most cases when I am confronted with this problem.

My question is:

1. What should I do if I want to stay as close as possible to the original sentence structure (for instance, maintaining the singular form of *scientist*?
2. What should I do in general when I am confronted with situations like this one? What options are there (e.g. converting to plural)?

Comment: What exactly is your problem with using the singular _they_, that you mention? It's common, widely accepted, and certainly long-established English usage. Grammatically _they_ may look and behave as a plural, but semantically it is singular. It's no different from using the (grammatically plural!) _you_ to refer to the second person singular (instead of _thou_).